# Vertical Style Button in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

How to design Asp.Net button same as below attached image using CSS.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check this:https://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/mHnvl

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using **asp.net buttons** in my web page and this style is not working with them, after I made few modifications in your suggested code. Also the text style of your suggested code is different from the image i had attached. Please help

Comment: Please some one help me to achieve this task.

Comment: Change 90deg to 270deg: -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */}

Comment: @Ruby I modified **#rotate** in your suggested link and achieved it. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Below link after few modifications in **#rotate** is working fine for my requirement:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjXpLE

```
    #rotate{
          margin-left:-26px;  
          vertical-align:top;
          margin-top:45px;
          width:auto;height:auto;
          transform:rotate(7deg);
          -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
          -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
          -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
          -o-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
      }
```

Thanks Ruby for the help.